# How to mock IAzureClientFactory<BlobServiceClient> correctly

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have a class with `IAzureClientFactory<BlobServiceClient>` as the parameter in the constructor as follows:

```
public class BlobStorageService
{
    readonly BlobServiceClient client;
    public BlobStorageService(IAzureClientFactory<BlobServiceClient> factory)
    {
        client = factory.CreateClient("AZGO")
    }
    
    ...other method to download, upload and delete files
}
```

I want to create the instance for the class. Using this approach failed when downloading a file in the blob storage.

```
var blobServiceClient = new Mock<BlobServiceClient>("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx");
var factory = new Mock<IAzureClientFactory<BlobServiceClient>>();
factory.Setup(c => c.CreateClient("AZGO").Returns(blobServiceClient.Object);

var service = new Mock<BlobStorageService>(factory.Object);
var instance = service.Object;
```

When I use it in the controller I am able to get the instance of BlobStorageService and I can download a file without any errors. I register the DI with the following method:

```
services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
{
    builder.AddBlobServiceClient(connectionString).WithName("AZGO");
});
services.AddScoped<BlobStorageService>();
```

Comment: How does it fail exactly? There are no setups for the members of `BlobServiceClient` so the real implementations will be used and try to download a file from Azure Storage (which most likely will fail unless valid credentials are provided). I'd not recommend downloading a file from BlobStorage in a unit test, because the tests could fail without an issue in the code, but for reasons in the infrastructe. Instead, I'd try to mock the downloads. Does this help? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/unit-testing-and-mocking/

Comment: @Markus `client.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);` returns null so I can't go to the next line. It's not null when called from controller not unittest

Comment: In this case, the real implementations are not used, but you have to add setups, e.g. `blobServiceClient.Setup(x => x.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName)).Returns(mockContainerClient)`. Unfortunately, this can end in a lot of mocks with a lot of setups. It's usually some trial and error, until you know which mocks and setups are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late reply, but I'm sure other people are still running into this challenge.
My teams solution to this problem, but beware as has been said in the comments, mocking this blob layer away means you will have to mock a lot of different layers...:

```
// Arrange
var mockBlobItem1 = new Mock<BlobItem>(); // You might want these blobs to also contain something, but just for the example
var mockBlobItem2 = new Mock<BlobItem>();
var mockBlobItem3 = new Mock<BlobItem>();

var page1 = Page<BlobItem>.FromValues(new[] { mockBlobItem1.Object, mockBlobItem2.Object }, "continuationToken", Mock.Of<Response>());
var lastPage = Page<BlobItem>.FromValues(new[] { mockBlobItem3.Object }, continuationToken: null, Mock.Of<Response>());

var asyncPageable = AsyncPageable<BlobItem>.FromPages(new[] { page1, lastPage });

var mockBlobContainerClient = new Mock<BlobContainerClient>();
mockBlobContainerClient.Setup(m => m.GetBlobsAsync(default, default, default, default)).Returns(asyncPageable);

var mockBlobServiceClient = new Mock<BlobServiceClient>();
mockBlobServiceClient.Setup(m => m.GetBlobContainerClient("blobContainerName")).Returns(mockBlobContainerClient.Object);

var blobService = new BlobService(mockBlobServiceClient.Object); // Test implementation with dependencies

var expected = new List<BlobItem>() { mockBlobItem1.Object, mockBlobItem2.Object, mockBlobItem3.Object };

// Act
var actual = await blobService.GetBlobsFromContainer("blobContainerName");

// Assert things here
```

On Act we're just calling a method that combines the result of the different pages, which was something we wanted in our application.

Then you could let the mock factory return the blobservice. And then inject that into your service :)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. One question, is `MockBlobService` meant to be `Mock<BlobService>` on the third-last line of code?

Comment: You mean from this line `var blobService = new MockBlobService(mockBlobServiceClient.Object);`? I will adjust it, it is a typo, but it's not meant to be `Mock<BlobService>` it's just supposed to be the service you want to test that needs the mocked dependencies :)